# My If function is not working to return data correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel, if

I have a worksheet full of data and I am trying to build a summary tab to put it in a format to view the information I need from the worksheet together.  It is a fairly simple IF function.

The first IF function works fine and returns the data correctly.

```
=IF($D$3='Week 5-8-23'!D:D,'Week 5-8-23'!B:B," ")
```

[image]

However, every time I try to add a new IF formula to return data from a different column, it is not working.

I have tried to enter the formula in a different order:

```
=IF(D3='Week 5-8-23'!D:D,'Week 5-8-23'!A:A," ")
=IF(($D$3='Week 5-8-23'!D:D),('Week 5-8-23'!B:B)," ")
=IF('Week 5-8-23'!D:D=D3,'Week 5-8-23'!F:F," ")
```

The only thing I am trying to change is which column the function looks at to return the data.  If the first IF fuction is working, why are the rest all returning a "false" result even if there is a TRUE showing when I am entering the formula?

[image]

Any help you can give is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It always returns "FALSE", because only one value actually matches your condition, i.e., one value in the range D:D is equal to D3. I assume that this is the claims no., and once you change the column you do not have a match anymore thats why you return only empty cells. To me it actually seems that you want a `VLOOKUP()` type procedure, rather than an `IF()` statement. However, given that you do not provide your data structure, it is difficult to judge. Do you have on your sheet "Week 5-8-23" and ID variable, e.g., the claim no. based on which you want to return values?

Comment: Yes, I am actually changing it to an XLOOKUP formula, thank you for your time!

Comment: If you provide a glimpse on your data structure or need support, just edit your question.

Comment: Week 5-8-23'!D:D=D3 Range= Value? All values in each cell = D3? You can try the FILTER function.